# Filtrar por contenido Array multidimensional, Programacion Funcional. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array, objeto, programación-funcional, ecmascript-6

esta vez necesito obtener el siguiente proposito, en principio obtengo un objeto, el cual llevo a un `array` multidimensional, del cual necesito sacar solo algunos dependiendo de su contenido, las cadenas de texto son fechas con su valor al lado, necesitaría sacar su fecha junto con su valor, ejemplo: obtener solo los del mes 09 en este caso serian `["09-25", 31.79],[ "09-26", 31.09 ]` estoy intentado usar programación funcional, trate utilizar `filter`pero no se como acceder a cada array en si.

```js
let objeto = { "08-15": 31.11, "09-25": 31.79, "09-26": 31.09, "10-01": 30.64, "10-02": 30.77 };

let array = Object.entries(objeto).map(([key, value]) => ([key, value]));

console.log(array);
```

agradezco la ayuda que puedan prestarme. La otra opción seria extraerlos desde el objeto directamente, gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes aplicar un filtro a tu array, tomando como ejemplo tu mismo arreglo, asi por ejemplo

```js
let objeto = { "08-15": 31.11, "09-25": 31.79, "09-26": 31.09, "10-01": 30.64, "10-02": 30.77 };

let array = Object.entries(objeto).map(([key, value]) => ([key, value]));

var filter=array.filter((o)=>o[0].split('-')[0]=="09");

console.log(filter);
```

Comment: estupendo, muchas gracias, podrias por favor definir `split`. Gracias!

Comment: la sintaxis la comprendo perfectamente, solo que no se que hace `.split` discúlpame soy novata :(

Comment: Split lo que hace es devolver un arreglo seccionando el string con el caracter que le damos como parametro en este caso el caracter es '-'. Saludos

Comment: estupendo, comprendo, muchas gracias!